# Integrar Woocommerce con PayPal y Mercadopago (Cambio de divisas)

Tags: wordpress, mercadopago, woocommerce, paypal

Buenas noches! Como no encontré mucha información al respecto, les hago la siguiente consulta.
Necesito vender productos desde mi sitio con **woocommerce** en pesos argentinos, utilizando las pasarelas de **MercadoPago** para usuarios de Argentina, y **Paypal** para compras en el exterior. El caso de ejemplo sería el siguiente:

Tengo un producto de 100$ ARS publicado en mi tienda. Si un cliente quiere comprarlo desde el exterior por **Paypal** se debería hacer la conversión a dolares automáticamente para poder abonar el valor correspondiente, pero no es lo que sucede, ya que el monto a abonar en Paypal es de 100 U$D, y eso no es correcto. Ahora bien, si un cliente compra el producto desde Argentina utilizando MercadoPago, abona el valor en pesos sin inconvenientes. Existe algún plugin de Paypal para Woocommerce que realice la conversión de divisas?

En todo caso estoy pensando en publicar los precios en dolares y quiza exista algun plugin de MercadoPago que realice la conversion de dolares a pesos.

Muchas gracias y espero puedan ayudarme!

Saludos

Comment: Gracias Luis por la bienvenida! No está clara la explicación? Ahora veo de editarla para que sea mas comprensible. Muchas gracias

Comment: Hola por favor mira: [ask].. Tambien de paso mira [Por que no somos soporte de Mercado pago](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2525/por-qu%c3%a9-no-somos-soporte-al-cliente-de-tu-compa%c3%b1%c3%ada-favorita). Eso no quiere decir que no consigas una respuesta, pero puede que no sea el lugar indicado!

Comment: Me sumo a la pregunta,
espero que exista forma de hacerlo posible ya que es muy necesario

Comment: Rodrigo, me pasas tu mail asi intercambiamos informacion y quiza llegamos a una solucion?

Comment: alguien lo resolvio???? necesito lo mismo